# Deleting xml strings in Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, string

I have on this moment too many xml string values. I started to delete the ones I don’t use, but this is quite hard (I don’t really know which I do use, and witch I don’t). Is there a function in eclipse that can do this for me, or help me whit it? (Like some call hierarchy)

Comment: I dont think there is a function like the one we have for java (search for references), so i think you need to search the java files of the whole project for R.string.XXXX having XXXX to be each string resource you have in your xml and the xml files for having references @string/XXXX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) should be able to help you with this.

On the website it states that it can do following things:

```
Missing translations (and unused translations)
Layout performance problems (all the issues the old layoutopt tool used to find, and more)
Unused resources
Inconsistent array sizes (when arrays are defined in multiple configurations)
Accessibility and internationalization problems (hardcoded strings, missing contentDescription, etc)
Icon problems (like missing densities, duplicate icons, wrong sizes, etc)
Usability problems (like not specifying an input type on a text field)
Manifest errors
```